# USB 'A' to USB 'A' Adapter - Female to Female

Tags: usb

Does a USB "A" to USB "A" adapter exist? I find USB 'A' to USB 'B' adapters like the one below [image: USB A-to-USB B adapter]

but I need one that has an 'A' adapter on both sides.

**Clarification** 
I have two cables that I would like to join together. Both cables are attached to something else on the other end. The end I have to work with is like the photo below. Is it possible to join the two cables together?

[image]

Comment: What exactly are you trying to join together?  Besides the two cables I mean...

Comment: There is a "crossover" cable designed specifically for machine-to-machine transfers.  Used to come in a package with the associated software.  Have not seen one recently, though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Male or female?

Here's some I found on Amazon:

- [USB Gender Changer, A Female To Female](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000BSN4UY)
- [USB Gender Changer, A Male To Male](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000BSJFO8)

For your future searching, the phrase `gender changer` really helps out.

<sub>*Edited to add…*</sub>

[image: usb plugs]

Three common USB plugs; from left to right: USB B, USB A female, USB A male.

Comment: No. I don't think that's the kind. I have 2 cables. Both have an end like this http://www.usbfirewire.com/Parts/images/rr-05200bbig.jpg. I need to join them together.

Comment: @RHPT, Yes, the [female-to-female adapter](http://www.amazon.com/dp/ASIN/B000BSN4UY) *is* the one.

Comment: @Synetech-inc.I bought this http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B000GHXTA0 this one and it didn't work. Isn't it the same?

Comment: @RHPT what do you mean it didn't work?  DID IT FIT. or DID IT NOT FIT?

Comment: @RHPT - I also added a picture above to make sure we're all talking about the same thing. Yes, if you have two cables that end with USB A male connectors, a USB A female/female gender changer should be what you want. Can you give some details about what "didn't work" with the one you have? And just to eliminate the obvious: did you try plugging them in both ways up? (I always get the white bit up v. down wrong on the first try, for some reason—and yes, I know the icons are supposed to help with that, but I often seem to be plugging things in by feel, where I can't see the icons.)

Comment: @barlop The adapter I bought (see comment above) did not fit. Was it supposed to fit?

@Dori The two cables I am trying to connect are USB A Male. Again, did the adaptor I purchased supposed to fit? 

How come I'm getting the feeling I'm starting to look like an ignoramous? ;)

Comment: @RHPT  OBVIOUSLY you are supposed to get getting an adaptor that fits. How else do you think you're going to connect your cables together. So you need an adaptor with a female A socket on each side of it. You are looking at it, any idea why it doesn't fit?  Does the USB cable plug into a USB socket in your computer? That's also female. It should fit into your computer's USB socket, or the USB A F-F gender changer, 'cos same socket. TEST

Comment: @RHPT - The USB A female and USB A male plugs should connect together. If they don't, there are three possible reasons: ① it isn't a USB A male plug, ② it isn't a USB A female plug, or ③ you're plugging them together incorrectly. Again: could you please be more specific than "didn't work"? Did the plugs not connect, or did they plug in fine, but the resulting hardware didn't do something? With the latter, for example, I can connect my USB microphone to my USB printer, but I wouldn't get a useful result. What are the cables attached to, and precisely what is the result you're trying to achieve?

Comment: I bought the one Dori linked to and it works. Thanks for all the help everyone.

Answer (score -1):

these are often cable extenders, or link cables with a circuit in between acting as virtual Bs, used for syncing/networking... between 2 computers, but now rarely seen because of the much more convenient LAN

> A<sub>1</sub>　↔　VirtualB<sub>1</sub>-VirtualB<sub>2</sub>　↔　A<sub>2</sub>

Comment: Any reason for the downvote? USB is a host driven standard unlike firewire so you **must** have a host device to act as master. There's no way to connect two As or two Bs directly. You'll have to use a link cable with special device in the middle. Any direct `A to A` or `B to B` connector with the same gender is non-standard