# Is there a micro-A USB female connector?

Tags: usb, connector

I've been searching around the web and am not able to find any female connector for the micro-A USB other than the micro-AB. On [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB#Host_and_device_interface_receptacles) the receptacle list doesn't show a micro-A female.

Was the male micro-A plug only able to fit into the AB port?

Comment: If there is a male Micro-A USB connector then there has to be a female plug, thats just how it works, cables might just not exist though.  But they [do](http://superuser.com/questions/278829/usb-a-to-usb-a-adapter-female-to-female?rq=1)

Comment: The female version that I usually see with the micro-A USB male is the micro-AB receptacle. I can't find just the micro-A female though.

Comment: What difference does it make if the AB receptacle works?

Comment: I'd like to know if the USB-IF ever included a micro-A receptacle in their specifications, and if not, why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no such thing as a micro-A receptacle.  There is only a micro-AB receptacle.  The Micro-USB Cables and Connectors Specification is available in the [USB 2.0 specification zip file](http://www.usb.org/developers/docs/usb20_docs/), and says:

> The Micro-USB specification defines the following additional
>   connectors:
>
> - Micro-B plug and receptacle
> - Micro-AB receptacle
> - Micro-A plug.

No micro-A receptacle.

> Was the male micro-A plug only able to fit into the AB port?

Yes.  This is shown in Table 4-1. "Plugs Accepted By Receptacles":

[image: Table 4-1. Plugs Accepted By Receptacles Receptacle Plugs Accepted Standard-A Standard-A Standard-B Standard-B Mini-B Mini-B Micro-B Micro-B Micro-AB Micro-A or Micro-B]

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the answer. I know it's been a while since I asked lol

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like micro A is necessarily included in micro AB, but nothing else, as, correct me if I'm wrong but the following quote seems to suggest A is responsible for power and not much else.

"The OTG device with the A-plug inserted is called the A-device and is responsible for powering the USB interface when required and by default assumes the role of host. The OTG device with the B-plug inserted is called the B-device and by default assumes the role of peripheral. An OTG device with no plug inserted defaults to acting as a B-device. If an application on the B-device requires the role of host, then the Host Negotiation Protocol (HNP) is used to temporarily transfer the host role to the B-device."

Comment: Indeed, it’s all related to USB OTG. Though almost no device manufacturer actually cares and most OTG-capable devices have Micro-B jacks. A Micro-A jack will always be compatible with Micro-B plugs, hence the name AB.